# How can I nest logical functions on LibreOffice?

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice

This is my test formula:

```
AND($E2<=10;OR($C2>=90;$D2>=90))
```

but nothing changes on my document.
Just the `OR`/`AND` formula behaves fine, like in:

```
OR($C2>=90;$D2>=90)
```

Is this the correct **method for nesting** `OR`/`AND` logical operators?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you've shown, assuming this is the logic you're trying to achieve.  You're showing the combination of E2<=10 plus either C2 or D2 >=90.  Is your question just to confirm this, or is it not doing what you expect?

Comment: @fixer1234: I thought that my rule was correct, but I was not sure. So, it is not doing what I expect (colorizing), I don't know why. Thanks you anyway, because at least I know the rule is correct now. I will post more info if I get it.